# How can I avoid getting the same posts twice

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, social-networking

I'm writing the code for a web application using PHP, MySQL, and javascript.

It's a very simple social network where users can create posts and see, like and comment other users posts. On the main page it loads posts and orders them based on an index based on the number of likes, comments and when the post was created.

Since I can't load every post at once (because ideally there can be millions of them), I load the top N posts and then when I scroll down it loads more posts (with an Ajax request) and adds them at the bottom  of the page. The problem is that since the posts are ordered dynamically, if I just limit the number of posts and then offset them in the later requests, I sometimes get the same post twice, and some posts never gets shown. How can I solve this?

Right now it just checks with javascript the id of every new post and it just discards the ones that are already on the page (checking the id of the posts on the page), but I dont like it because every time it loads more posts it has to check if every single post is already on the page or not and if the number of post grows it will get very slow.

Comment: Something to consider - why not send the IDs of the already loaded / shown posts and the current lowest number of votes when making the AJAX call? That way, you can build your query like this (I'm assuming MySQL): `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.id NOT IN (<ids_from_AJAX> AND post.votes <= <current_minimum> LIMIT <your_chosen_posts_batch_size>)`? Also, with the logic you currently have, what would happen if a post suddenly gets a lot of votes? Would it be shown / be attached to the page? If so, where? Somewhere in the middle, at the top, at the bottom, etc?

Comment: Ok i guess that sending the IDs of the posts i already have makes sense, but you still have to go through every post every time you wanna load more to create the query. Right now it just loads N more posts from the database and then discard the ones already on the page, so unless the post is in the N more i load that time it wouldnt be shown, and even if it was it would be at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of processing power in the server and you're able to do the scoring for any time in the past (e.g. taking into account only likes previous this time), you can make your page send: (1) the timestamp of the first loading, and (2) the number of post already there (or, better, the score of the worst post it received, because posts could have been deleted since then).

Let the server compute the list of the past and send the next posts.

If you have more memory in the server than processing power, then you could just save a copy of the scored list for some time (1h, 24h…) whenever someone request it.

And if you want the server to send the new best post of the moment: if you know the present listing and you know what the user already got (with their timestamp and last score they got), you can make the server removes what they already have and gives them the rest.

Comment: The first solution is interesting, but unfortunately I have no way of calculating the score in a past Timestamp because the number of likes is stored directly in the post table. Saving a copy of the scored list would be possible but wouldn't it require too much memory once the users and number of posts grow?